# Gecko proxy Ip and port in same textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, ip, port, gecko

I want to know if it's possible to make a gecko proxy and insert ip and port in same textbox like webbrowser.
Is it possible?

I've tried this code

```
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1; 
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http") = TextBox2.Text; 
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http_port") = 8080;
```

and tried to change

```
skybound.gecko.geckopreference.user("network.proxy.http")=textbox2 & ("network.proxy.http_port") = textbox2.text
```

It doesn't work to put ip and port in same textbox.

Comment: Welcome to SO jake! What have you tried? Have you researched anything?

Comment: i've tried this code   Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1;
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http") = TextBox2.Text;
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http_port") = 8080; and trying to change "skybound.gecko.geckopreference.user("network.proxy.http)=textbox2 & ("network.proxy.http_port") = textbox2.text but is wrong

Comment: When you say "but is wrong," what is wrong? Also, edit your original post and put your code in their so it's easier to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Modify file :xulrunner.js and add to end:

```
pref("network.proxy.http", "162.208.49.45");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", 7808);
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

And you code before to navigate method:

```
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.type") = 1
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.http") = 'You proxy ip'
    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.http_port") = Integer.Parse('Proxy_port_in_int')
```